# Issue with seeder between 3 entities

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have an issue with the seeder news. It has a relationship between 2 entities. The result of the command php artisan db:seed is the next:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Fi
>   eld 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `news` (`title`, `b
>   ody`, `author`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (Dr., Nisi quia et provident
>   expedita voluptatem debitis quas. Ut in dicta magni voluptatum hic facere adipis
>   ci. Eum aut porro voluptatem est sit numquam ex a., Janiya Lowe, 2019-09-19 06:5
>   4:25, 2019-09-19 06:54:25))

I have 3 entities:

```
User                          News                             Category
id                             id                                id                                              
                              user_id                         
                              category_id
```

My NewsTableSeeder is the next:

```
public function run()
    {
        factory(News::class, 20)->create()->each(function ($news) {
            $news->category()->save(factory(NewsCategory::class)->make());
            $news->writtenBy()->save(factory(User::class)->make());
        });
    }
```

My class News is the next

```
class News extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'news';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'author', 'created_at', 'update_at'];

    /**
     * WrittenBy belongs to User.
     */
    public function writtenBy()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * Category belongs to User.
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(NewsCategory::class);
    }
}
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Check This,

```
public function run()
    {
 DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
        factory(News::class, 20)->create()->each(function ($news) {
            $news->category()->save(factory(NewsCategory::class)->make());
            $news->writtenBy()->save(factory(User::class)->make());
        });
 DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
    }
```

Comment: hi @smzihan, if you could explain what is the changes and why it was put there. that would be splendid.

Comment: In news table user_id is foreign key. So When you insert data then  set  FOREIGN_KEY_CHECK  is zero...after inserting data it's set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECK.Its because not to check foreign_key this time

Comment: Thx for your answer but the result is the same. My table user and newscategory is not empty